# missing Email Send Throttling in automation studio

Tags: automationstudio

there is a 'Email Send Throttling' feature in 'User Initiated Emails' but does anyone know if the same feature can be used in Automation Studio?

i can't find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The option doesn't exist in a regular email send configuration, but you did just give yourself the answer.

When setting up an Email Send in Automation Studio, you can either create a new send process, or select an existing User Initiated Email. By having the throttling already defined in the user initiated email, you can throttle through Automation Studio.

[image]

Click on 'Send Definition Template' to access your User Initiated Emails.

Good luck!